# Should a question be put on a dedicated external forum in preference to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I recently inadvertently caused a stir by asking a question that a commentator though could be asked on an external dedicated forum (comment & discussion has been removed by a moderator now).

The question itself was a valid question (nobody suggested the question itself was off-topic / invalid / not in accordance with guidance), just that using an external forum would be a 'better' place for it as if there were insufficient people with knowledge on that site.

The short comment debate (before it was removed) seemed to suggest that some members partially hold opinions similar to the following:

1. If a dedicated external forum exists for a topic then that should be used and not a stack overflow site.
2. If it isn't a common topic which the active posters are typically unfamiliar with then it's probably not worth posting here.

The first seems inconsistent to me; there are dedicated forums for everything so if you follow that logic then stack overflow might as well close up shop or be unsuccessful (in contradiction to the observed success)

The second seems to suggest to be that some active members don't want to broaden the searchable knowledge base available here.

Please can readers (presumably active posters) let me know what the common view is on these 2 viewpoints are so I can decide where to post in the future.

(Of course it could just be commentators seizing on an excuse for an argument).

Comment: Can you provide a link to that question? Or a quote if it's deleted?

Comment: Was this definitely on SO? You don't have what I'd consider recent activity and you don't have any deleted comments on any posts here...

Comment: What are these "external forums" you mention? Other sites in the SE network? Completely unrelated sites?

Comment: If your question is https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic you're welcome to post it.

Comment: There are multiple ways in which SO users try to be helpful.  Telling you that you might have better luck to find a solution at another web site is certainly one of them.  It is merely advice, that is all, try not to hate good advice too much.

Comment: There is one specific category of question which should be directed to dedicated forums: product support questions.

Comment: External: Unrelated

Comment: Stack overflow site: Anything run by the same guys reachable via the API

Comment: From some responses there seems to be the presumption of nefarious purpose (which helps me calibrate other interactions of course)

Comment: I'm specifically referring to a question that abides by the guidelines and is not voted down (only up; which is still true despite the downvote bandit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can't answer this without specific details, like a link to the question and what kind of dedicated external forum you're talking about.

> #1 seems inconsistent to me; there are dedicated forums for everything so if you follow that logic then stack overflow might as well close up shop or be unsuccessful (in contradiction to the observed success)

This isn't what I would call a good faith argument. You're following that logic to an absurd conclusion, not a reasonable one. Were the commenters talking about *official* forums where you can get support directly from a company that sells a product? We don't know, because you haven't shared those details.

> #2 seems to suggest to be that some active members don't want to broaden the searchable knowledge base available here.

Again, we don't know. There are some questions that are better asked elsewhere. We can't list all of those here. We can only point to [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

> (Of course it could just be commentators seizing on an excuse for an argument)

Or, possibly, they were trying to help you find a better place to get an answer to your question.

Comment: I'm curious how #1 is either bad faith or absurd.  I would describe the argument as such rather than the objection

Comment: I didn't ask for a list of topics, but what the active members prefer; I'm indirectly getting that information so this was a valuable exercise for me